# Is there a cleaner way to filter by key's value?

Tags: php, arrays, filter

```
$a = array(
    0 => array( 'one' => 1, 'two' => 2 ),
    1 => array( 'one' => 3, 'two' => 4 ),
    2 => array( 'one' => 5, 'two' => 2 )
);

$c = count( $a );
$r = array();
for ( $i = 0; $i < $c; $i++ )
{
    if ( $a[$i]['two'] == 2 )
        $r[] = $a[$i];
}
```

Is there a cleaner way then to do all of the above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried using [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-filter.php)?

```
$r = array_filter($a, function($var) {
  return ($var['two'] === 2);
});
```

The output of the above is slightly different than your original code:

```
Yours:
array(
  0 => array('one' => 1, 'two' => 2),
  1 => array('one' => 5, 'two' => 2)
)

Using array_filter:
array(
  0 => array('one' => 1, 'two' => 2),
  2 => array('one' => 5, 'two' => 2)    // Note the key is 2, not 1
)
```

If you need the keys collapsed, you can follow up the `array_filter()` with [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-values.php) or [`array_multisort()`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-multisort.php)

Comment: Definitely the way I would go for. It's just important to notice that `array_filter` persists keys from original array.

Comment: +1 This is the best answer. For PHP older than 5.3 the anonymous function should be replaced with [`create_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) call. Just as a notice for people with older PHP versions.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function to do just this and then use [array_walk](https://www.php.net/array_walk) or [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) but that's about it.

Only way I can see to clean it up more would be to change the original datastructure.